# kernel GridSearchCV parameters

Tags: python, kernel, svm, gridsearchcv

can we search for the kernel in Gridserach as below:

and what parameters combinations we should avoid?

```
parameters = {'C': [0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000],  
              'gamma': [1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001,'auto'], 
              'kernel': ['linear', 'poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid']} 
  Svm = GridSearchCV(Svm, param_grid=parameters, cv=kf,verbose=10)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In principle, you can search for the kernel in GridSearch. But you should keep in mind that `'gamma'` is only useful for `‘rbf’`, `‘poly’` and `‘sigmoid’`. That means You will have redundant calculation when `'kernel'` is `'linear'`. The better way is to use a list of dictionaries rather than a dictionary as an input parameter of `param_grid`:

```
svm_linear = {'C': [0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000], 
              'kernel': ['linear']} 
svm_others = {'C': [0.1, 1, 10, 100, 1000],
              'gamma': [1, 0.1, 0.01, 0.001, 0.0001,'auto'], 
              'kernel': ['poly', 'rbf', 'sigmoid']}
parameters = [svm_linear, svm_others]
Svm = GridSearchCV(Svm, param_grid=parameters, cv=kf,verbose=10)
```

You could find the similar parameters setting in the scikit-learn document: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/model_selection/plot_grid_search_digits.html

I hop this answer is useful for you. :)